# Disallow password authentication in Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I'm using Fabric (via cuisine) to configure devices on the local subnet.  The first step is to scan all the devices on the subnet and work out if it's one of the devices to be configured.  The command is:

```
cuisine.connect(ip_addr, user='pi')
```

I only want to configure devices which already have my ssh key on them.  So I'm trying to connect without a password.  If the connect succeeds, I know it's got my key on it.  If not, I want the connect to fail immediately.  However what I'm seeing is a command line prompt for a password.

Is there a way to prevent the prompt and just fail immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used cuisine, but looking briefly over the source i think you you do:

```
import fabric.api
fabric.api.env.abort_on_prompts = True
cuisine.connect(ip_addr, user='pi')
```

Theoretically it should work..

PS. must resist the urge to PEP8 that project... so hard...